# Read Image From Acess Data Ole Object

Tags: sql, vb.net

I cannot read the image from access file using ole object,
above is my coding, please help me solve it.

Error Message:Error 3   Value of type 'System.Drawing.Image' cannot be converted to 'String'.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To Row

    pic(i) = New PictureBox

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM packageDetail WHERE packageDetailID = ?"
    objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbconn)

    objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@packageID", i))

    reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader()

    reader.Read()

    Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(reader(11), Byte())
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))

    With pic(i)
        .Name = "pic(" & i.ToString & ")"
        .Image = Image.FromFile(img)

        .Visible = True
        .Left = 15
        .Width = 201
        .Height = 142
        .Top = 9
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you create an image from the bytes read:

```
Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
```

Here you are trying to use that image like a filename:

```
.Image = Image.FromFile(img)
```

`ImageFromFile` requires a filename (string), you are passing image. This should work:

```
.Image = img
```

You should be disposing of the memstream:

```
Dim imgData As Byte()
imgData = TryCast(rdr.Item("Image"), Byte())
If imgData IsNot Nothing Then
     Using ms As New MemoryStream(imgData )
        img = CType(Image.FromStream(ms), Bitmap)
    End Using
End If
```